# eslint not working in Atom for react native project

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, eslint

`linter` and `linter-eslint` modules are installed in Atom

Create a react native project

```
react-native init AwesomeApp
```

Install requisite node modules

```
yarn add babel-eslint eslint-config-airbnb-base eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-native --dev
```

Create `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "modules": true
    }
  },
  "extends" : [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb-base"
  ],
  "rules" : {
    "arrow-body-style" : 'warn'
  }
}
```

When I open Atom I get an error

[image: Atom eslint error]

Here is the stack trace from the dev tools:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:159 [Linter] Error running ESLint Error: Failed to load plugin react-native: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react-native'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at Object.load (/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/plugins.js:134:29)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.loadAll (/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/plugins.js:162:21)
    at Object.load (/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:541:21)
    at loadConfig (/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:63:33)
    at new Config (/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:229:42)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:741:28)
    at lintJob (/Volumes/Macintosh HD 3/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/lib/worker.js:50:51)
```

Atom is up to date, I'm running 1.18.0 x64

`eslint-plugin-react-native` is definitely installed within the project. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

For me, removing this line worked:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
```